# Group by col1 and sum col2 by each grup? In SQL, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to extend my other question.

So here's my query:

```
select COL1, sum(col_a+col_b) as col_name2, count(col) as col_qty from tab
```

This is my table:

```
COL1    col_name2   col_qty
alpha   2              3             
alpha   1              4             
alpha   8              2             
beta    2              5             
beta    6              4            
gamma   1              1             
gamma   2              4             
gamma   1              1             
gamma   1              3
```

And how I need it to be like:

```
COL1    col_name2   col_qty
alpha   11             9
beta    8              9
gamma   5              9
```

How should it be done?

Comment: Do you want both `col_a` and `col_b` `SUM` results in the same column?  I'm not understanding your format.

Comment: *"I'd like to extend my other question."*: what other question?  Each question you write should be complete by itself.  Right now, the question is missing important information which doesn't allow us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is not a working query, there's no GROUP BY.

Comment: @dnoeth Not really, you can use it without group by like `SELECT count(*), sum(sales) from TABLE` is valid statement

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: There's `COL1` in the SELECT list and you need to put in GROUP BY (unless you're using MySQL and want some random result)

Comment: @dnoeth I mean I agree he need put a `group by` to get the result he want. But that is a working query. You can do something like this to calculate percentage `SELECT mySales / Sum(mySales) FROM Sales` and is perfect valid

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: No it's not valid in Oracle and most other DBMSes (besides MySQL)

Comment: @sstan, I was just explaining why I add a very similar questions, one right after another. I thought it's all complete here. If not, please tell me what. Till then.. your comment is missing important information :)

Comment: @Siyual , that's the thing - col_name2 is already a sum of two columns. Therefore, if I want to sum all col_name2 row, those which are alpha, I cannot use sum anymore.

Comment: @dnoeth , that's the thing - I don't know how to group it properly. COL1 would be grouped by same values (alpha, beta, gamma) and other columns sumed for those groups. So col_name2 is already a sum, that's why I cannot (?) sum 'alpha' rows in that column.

Comment: Can you add some actual data, and what's your expected result. It's probably either a nested aggregate using a Derived Table (Oracle call it Inline View) or a `SUM(...) OVER ()`

Comment: The problem is that `select COL1, sum(col_a+col_b) as col_name2, count(col) as col_qty from tab` is not a valid query.  What is the query you are actually using?  And what table are you running the query against?  I don't see any table definition in your description that has columns `col_a`, `col_b`, etc... The question is either incorrect or incomplete.  It makes it very hard to answer.

Comment: @sstan I see. Than I'll focus on the very point of my question – having `sum(col_a+col_b)`, I sum values of two columns "horizontally". And it results with one column. Now, I need to sum this column "vertically", within my `alpha` group of, the other column. And it's the same with `count(col)` - I need a one, col sum number for all `alpha`. Is it more clear like this?

Comment: @Andy: No, it's not clear.  Your best best is to edit your question this way: define your table structure, provide some sample data, show your current query, what results you are currently getting, and what results you actually want.  If you can post a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) link that has the initial setup and your current query, that will be even better!  If you do this, you will get good answers very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a specific column and a aggregate function, you have to group your results by the column(s).

```
select COL1, sum(col_a), sum(col_b), sum(col_a + col_b), count(col1) from tab group by COL1
```

in general it's:

```
Select [Columns, aggregate functions] 
from [table] where [condition] 
group by [all columns from select] 
having [condition]
```

the where clause is used to filter by columnvalues, the having clause to filter by results of aggregate functions.

Comment: Not really, you can use it without `group by` like `SELECT count(*) from TABLE` is valid statement

Comment: that's right, you have to group it when you select a specific column and a  aggregate function. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Using a group by statement:

select COL1, sum(col_name2), sum(col_qty) from tab group by col1

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one, it will work

```
select col1,sum(col_name2) as col_name2 ,sum(col_qty) as col_qty
from tab 
group by col1;
```